# Reset rotation of pivot point

Tags: modeling, vertices

My pivot point in edit mode have weird rotation. [image: enter image description here[1]] How I can reset it to normal?.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I solve it :D 
[image]

On the right panel in TransformOrientation you must click on global. :))